# How to alias a column name in LINQ at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
```

And this is my query

```
var q = from o in list
      select new
      {
        column1 = o.X
      };
```

This works but I want to set column1 at runtime as follows:

```
string column1 = "myColumnName";
var q = from o in list
    select new
    {
       column1 = o.X 
    };
```

How do I do that?

Comment: why you think you need this?

Comment: what you are trying to do is not clear, can you elaborate?

Comment: you would have to build your `Expression` manually at runtime and compile it

Comment: Would you explain it more or give me a reference MichaC?

Comment: possibly you need use `Dictionary` instead of anonymous type?

Comment: @Alborz so you can set `ValueMember` to `Value`, and `DisplayMember` to `Key` and use `Dictionary` as datasource

Comment: I know this can be done in a simpler way, but I confess I'm curious to know how would be the code to create an anonymous type at runtime.

Comment: @ConradClark [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121568/Dynamic-Type-Using-Reflection-Emit) :-)

Answer (score 1):

As i understand from your comment you need not alias for column at runtime, you need something like this

```
string columnName = "myColumnName";
var q = from o in list
        select new KeyValuePair<string,string>(columnName,o.X);
```

and bind this to combobox like this

```
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
comboBox.DataSource = q;
comboBox.DataBind();
```